# Detecting Reachability

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have Reachability class that I adopted from Apple. My problem is implementing my reachability detection in my ListViewController rather than in the ReachabilityAppDelegate shown in Apple. My problems:

1. I want to link the calling method in the (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView 
   *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath and the reachability detection
2. I am trying to disable my cell if they detect it is not connected and enable the cell if it
   is connected

This is coded in viewDidLoad:

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];
```

The reachabilityChanged as below:

```
-(void) reachabilityChanged: (NSNotification* )note{
  Reachability* curReach = [note object];
  NSParameterAssert([curReach isKindOfClass:[Reachability class]]);
  [self updateInterfaceWithReachability: curReach];
}
```

How do I implement my disabling of UITableViewCells in

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

- Take note that I have coded this in the above method:

  ```
  NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
      NSString *contentForThisRow = nil;

      static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

      if (tableView == [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView]) {
          // Sort search results in alphabetical order
          NSArray *sorted = [searchResults sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
          contentForThisRow = [sorted objectAtIndex:row];
      }else {
          contentForThisRow = [nameArray objectAtIndex:row];
      }
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

          if (cell == nil) {
              cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier]autorelease];
          }
          // Set Device names into Cells
          cell.textLabel.text = contentForThisRow;
          cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
  NSLog(@"Load cell done");
  ```

  }

Comment: You can try https://github.com/GlennChiu/GCNetworkReachability which is a little better.

Comment: Thanks. But I still do not know how to implement it with my project. I am still new to objective c.

Comment: Download it from the site, theres a button that says zip. then drag the 2 files into the app project and make sure the .m file is being compiled (under build phases and compile source), then in the class you want to add type #import "" and import it in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can code like this , add an instance var `BOOL _isOffline`
in the class and in your `updateInterfaceWithReachability:` method

```
- (void)updateInterfaceWithReachability:(Reachability* )curReach
{
    if(curReach == XXXXNotReachable)
    {
        //your code
        _isOffline = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        _isOffline = NO;
    }
    [_tableView reloadData];
}
```

in your `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

you should add your code to deal with the cell , may be

```
if(_isOffline)
{
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
else
{
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But what xxxNotReachable? Is this the same as Not Reachable?

Comment: @MrExperimental yes , its your NotReachable enum , because different version of Reachability the NotReachable enum`name is different , so xxxNotReachable is your Not Reachable enum`s name.

Comment: @MrExperimental ... the _tableView is your cell`s tableView , find out your tableView`s name and change the _tableView with your name

Comment: Done. But, I've realised that I need to put an ip address eg. "www.google.com" to check whether my app is connected to it or not. How I can compare it? How do implement it?

Comment: @MrExperimental you can see the "ReadMe" to learn how to use Reachibility via this : https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

Comment: Reachability* reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"]; Where in the method above created by you, can i add this?

Comment: @MrExperimental you should add that in the - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions  method

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not have that method in my project. Must I declare a new one? Or can I put in in my FullViewController.m viewDidLoad? I'm confused.

Comment: @MrExperimental it is in your AppDelegate.m

Comment: @MrExperimental do your know Chinese ? I have a Chinese web to introduct the Reachibility

Comment: @MrExperimental maybe you can google it , I think there are a lot of documents of Reachibility

Comment: Im not chinese. Is there simpler way for me to use the "Reachability* reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];" for me to compare? I am trying to code the above codes in the ListViewController and FullViewController.

Comment: @MrExperimental do not code it in the ListViewController or FullViewController . code it in the AppDelegate.m , maybe you should search a demo in the github

Comment: I have a lot of classes in my project. By coding it in my appdelegate, will it corrupt if I have imported the appdelegate for other class?

Comment: Where should i place my this :  if ([self reachable]) {
  
  [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
  cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
 }
 else {
  [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
  cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
 }
This is in my ListView: -(BOOL)reachable {
    Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"google.com"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];
    if(internetStatus == NotReachable) {
        return NO;
    }
 return YES;
}